# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ui.context.ThemeSource

Tags: java, spring

I am getting this error when running my login jsp. I am kind of new at using spring and I'm at a lost. I have all the dependencies for the servlets and beans. Here is my login.jsp code:

```
<%@include file="include.jsp"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form:form id="loginForm" method="post" action="login" modelAttribute="userDAO">

            <form:label path="username">Enter your user-name</form:label>
            <form:input id="username" name="username" path="username" /><br>
            <form:label path="username">Please enter your password</form:label>
            <form:password id="password" name="password" path="password" /><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, the loginController:

```
package com.onlinemarket3.controllers;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.onlinemarket3.delegate.LoginDelegate;
import com.onlinemarket3.model.Buyer;
import com.onlinemarket3.model.User;
import com.onlinemarket3.model.UserDao1;
import com.onlinemarket3.model.UserDaoInterface;



@Controller
public class LoginController
{
    @Autowired
    private LoginDelegate loginDelegate;

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
        User user = new User();

        model.addObject("userDAO", user);
        return model;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView executeLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("userDAO")User user)
    {
        ModelAndView model= null;
        boolean loggedIn;
        try {
            loggedIn = loginDelegate.autentificate(user);
            if (loggedIn) {
                System.out.println("User Login Successful");
                request.setAttribute("loggedInUser", user.getUsername());
                model = new ModelAndView("welcome");

            }
            else
            {
                model = new ModelAndView("login");
                model.addObject("userDAO", user);
                request.setAttribute("message", "Invalid credentials!!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return model;
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ui/context/ThemeSource
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:865)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
    org.apache.jsp.jsps.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:93)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

It also says that I have an error at line 10 in login.jsp. 
I have not found a clue to this error on google. Please help, thank you! :)

Comment: What is in your `include.jsp` look like?

Comment: just this: <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

Answer (score 0):

The [ThemeSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/context/ThemeSource.html) class is located in the spring-context jar. Make sure that the required dependency is included in your pom.xml file e.g.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>X.X.X.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have the dependency in pom.xml. It's just that, right? or you have to actually have to add the jar to the classpath?

Comment: You should only need it in your pom. Try running project as maven install.